# Custom Field doesn't appear in Drupal views using civicrm entity module

Tags: custom-fields, drupal-views, civicrm-entity

I'm trying to use the Drupal module civicrm entity in views to render a custom field (Image) I created in contacts in civicrm 4.7.13, I did the views integration through settings.php and in views when I add the field provided by CIVICRM Entity I get the error:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'civicrm_contact.custom_4' in 'field list'

The field provided as "Custom Data Field" in views works but it only displays a link to the uploaded image and I need it as an entity to apply image styles on it, etc..

Comment: As of CiviCRM Entity Beta 8, CiviCRM Entity no longer exposes  the custom fields to views. You should use the handlers that come with the stock CiviCRM module.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the link to the image file in the view then I would try rewriting the results of that field. Set it up as an 
`<img src=[token that has path to image] />`.

Then you can add a class to it and style it as you wish.

Comment: Hi. I have a similar problem i.e. I am using a single civicrm and drupal database for an older site and any custom data is not showing in the views. We have added a few custom fields in cases which we want to expose as views but the custom fields don't show up. I get the error. SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'civicrm_case.custom_27' in 'field list'. How can I resolve this?

Comment: As of CiviCRM Entity Beta 8, CiviCRM Entity no longer exposes the custom fields to views. You should use the handlers that come with the stock CiviCRM module.